# Spilt strings with comma but ignoring space in Java

Tags: java

For example:

```
string s = "123, 1 23,   , ,      ,1,,,";
```

Store the result into `string[] str`

I want the result of:

```
123
 1 23
1
```

and the length of `str` should be 3.

Thank you!

Comment: Remember, `split` accepts a *regex*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested this and it works for your example:

```
String s = "123, 1 23,   , ,      ,1,,,";
String[] usefulParts = s.split(",(?:[, ]*,)*");
List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(usefulParts);
System.out.println("Result:\n" + asList);
```

The output is:

```
Result:
[123,  1 23, 1]
```

The pattern provided to `split` simply says "match a comma and then optionally match any sequence of commas and spaces which ends with a comma". This won't match spaces between data, and it will preserve the space at the start of the data element " 1 23".

I've converted to a `List<String>` just to make the result print nicely, but there's no need to convert the array to a `List` to get the desired result.

Comment: I have modified the regex in my answer so that it preserves the space found at the start of valid data. (Usually such leading space is undesirable, however.)

Answer (score 0):

`split` accept regex which represents place on which split should happen. From your example it looks like this regex should match part marked with `^`

```
123, 1 23,   , ,      ,1,,,
   ^#    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^
    based on your example I assume that this space marked with #
    should stay in result
```

In other words it should match one or more occurrences of `zero-or-more spaces` with `comma` after it.

Such regex can look like `(\s*,)+`

So your code can look like:

```
String str = "123, 1 23,   , ,      ,1,,,";
for (String s : str.split("(\\s*,)+")){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
123
 1 23
1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String s = "123, 1 23,   , ,      ,1,,,";
    String []str=s.split(",(?:[, ]*,)*");
    for(String str1:str){
        System.out.println(str1);
    }
```

here Output is

```
123
 1 23
1
```

Comment: This approach was already posted by Bobulous over 5 minutes before you post your answer. If you agree with other answers you should upvote them, not repost them.

Comment: @Pshemo - it's just 3 mins before, and if you see both answers having diff regex.

Comment: I was *not* referring to *my* answer but to [answer posted by Bobulous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30013016). Take a look at its timing (it is more than 3 minutes older than your answer) and proposed regex (it is exactly same as one from your answer).